# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404 shows when trying to get data from MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, axios

I am trying to use the Get method from the code below. I can use the Post method to post new instances to the database but my Get method is not working. When I tried to use the Get method I encountered the "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404" error.

This is my code that contains the Get and Post methods:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const { connectToDb, getDb, URI } = require('./db');
const Root = require('../models/Root');
const port = process.env.PORT || 7000;
const URL = 'http://localhost:7000'
const axios = require('axios');

// init & middleware
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.set('bufferCommands', false);

let db
connectToDb((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  }
});

mongoose.connect(URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// POST
app.post('/roots', async (req, res) => {
  const { root_id, node_id, name } = req.body;
  if (!root_id || !node_id || !name) {
    return res
      .status(400).send({ error: 'Please provide all required fields' });
  }
  const root = new Root({ root_id, node_id, name });
  try {
    const savedRoot = await root.save();
    res.send(root);
  } catch (err) {
    //console.error('Error saving root:', err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});

// GET
app.get('/roots/:root_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${URL}/roots?filter={"where":{"root_id":${req.params.root_id}}}`
    );
    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error getting root:', err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
    // res.status(500).json({ error: 'Could not fetch the root' });
  }
});

// DELETE
app.delete('/roots/:root_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`${URL}/roots/${req.params.root_id}`);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Root deleted successfully' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error getting root:', err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
    // res.status(500).json({ error: 'Could not delete the root' });
  }
  // Call to a method to delete all children nodes of the tree in the Node tables
});

// PATCH
app.patch('/roots/:root_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.patch(
      `${URL}/roots/${req.params.root_id}`,
      req.body
    );
    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Could not update the root' });
  }
});
```

I use this code to connect to the database:

```
// Use this file to connect to database - easy to switch between local and cloud for testing
const{MongoClient} = require('mongodb')

let dbConnection
// Connect to local database
let URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/PM_AI'

module.exports = {
    connectToDb: (cb) => {
        MongoClient.connect(URI)
        // MongoClient.connect(cloudURI)
         .then((client) => {
            dbConnection = client.db()
            return cb()
         })
         .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            return cb(err)
         })
    },
    getDb: () => dbConnection,
    URI
}
```

ERROR LOG for the error that I encounter:

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 404",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (D:\\CSDS_395_Project\\AI-PM\\node_modules\\axios\\dist\\node\\axios.cjs:1900:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\\CSDS_395_Project\\AI-PM\\node_modules\\axios\\dist\\node\\axios.cjs:2944:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "User-Agent": "axios/1.3.3",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
        },
        "method": "get",
        "url": "http://localhost:7000/roots?filter={\"where\":{\"root_id\":1}}"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 404
}
```

The URL that I use to test my method in Postman is `http://localhost:7000/roots/1`.
Please let me know what am I doing wrong with my code here.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Tangential, but I don't see why you'd make a complete HTTP request to your own endpoint when the code that implements that endpoint is already available to you.

Answer (score 0):

In your expressjs server file, the url you are using in mongoose.connect() refers to the expressjs server itself instead of localhost mongodb instance

So in your server.js/app.js or whatever is your main expressjs server file,

```
const MONGO_URL =  'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/PM_AI'
```

I can also see that you are using both mongo client and mongoose which I don't understand why... You only need one of these libaries to connect to mongodb from your backend

Also your code is pretty messed up so I've made the following changes

1. No need to use mongoose strict query and other configurations, simply using mongoose.connect() in latest mongoose version is enough. As mongodb connection establishes, you can launch your server
2. In terminal, write npm install dotenv. It is a package that is used to access variables in .env file, without it your server won't work properly
3. I've removed mongo client as it is not needed, simply using mongoose is enough
4. I don't know why you are making axios requests to your own server. This axios thing is what is causing 404 error. You should use axios only when you need to make api calls from frontend, or make api calls from your backend to some other backend server. For your own server, you should always prefer using a controller function for every route otherwise you will get 404 error. By controller function, I mean instead of axios.get, you need to execute mongoModel.delete() instead of axios.delete() or return mongoModel.findById() instead of axios.get()
5. For mongodb connection, use MONGO_URL and for connecting your own server, use URL

So the final version of your code should look like:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const Root = require('../models/Root');
const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/PM_AI'
const axios = require('axios');

// For environmental variables in .env file
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()

// init & middleware
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(express.json());


const port = process.env.PORT || 7000
const URL = `http://localhost:${port}`

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL).then(() => {
console.log("Mongodb connected")
app.listen(port,() => 
{console.log("Server started") }
});

// POST
app.post('/roots', async (req, res) => {
  const { root_id, node_id, name } = req.body;
  if (!root_id || !node_id || !name) {
    return res
      .status(400).send({ error: 'Please provide all required fields' });
  }
  const root = new Root({ root_id, node_id, name });
  try {
    const savedRoot = await root.save();
    res.send(root);
  } catch (err) {
    //console.error('Error saving root:', err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});

// GET
app.get('/roots/:root_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${URL}/roots?filter={"where":{"root_id":${req.params.root_id}}}`
    );
    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error getting root:', err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
    // res.status(500).json({ error: 'Could not fetch the root' });
  }
});

// DELETE
app.delete('/roots/:root_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`${URL}/roots/${req.params.root_id}`);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Root deleted successfully' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error getting root:', err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
    // res.status(500).json({ error: 'Could not delete the root' });
  }
  // Call to a method to delete all children nodes of the tree in the Node tables
});

// PATCH
app.patch('/roots/:root_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.patch(
      `${URL}/roots/${req.params.root_id}`,
      req.body
    );
    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Could not update the root' });
  }
});
```